# Group roles into one checkbox in Sonata form

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a form in my Sonata panel to set roles to a group

[image]

I want to have the same roles field with checkboxes so I have add `'expanded' => true` to my field

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name')
        ->add('roles', SecurityRolesType::class, [
            'expanded' => true,
        ])
    ;
}
```

But I get this

[image]

I'm trying to group this roles `ROLE_ADMIN_USER_EDIT`, `ROLE_ADMIN_USER_LIST`... to `ROLE_ADMIN_USER`

I tried with some options I find here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html but nothing worked

How can I group this roles like my first screenshot but with checkboxes ?

Thanks

Comment: Another way would be you create groups using roles you need to group like create a group with roles `ROLE_ADMIN_USER_EDIT, ROLE_ADMIN_USER_LIST` and name group as `Admin user` now in your entity define a `ManyToMany` relation with groups entity and then in your form add groups filed and select as many groups you want for your entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to override the Sonata `base_edit_form_macro` template and change the default rendering

```
{# If field name is `roles` then override classic extended multiple select #}
{% if field_name == 'roles' %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {# Render form field name #}
        <label for="roles_field"
               class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        >
            {{ field_name|capitalize }}
        </label>
        <div id="roles_field"
             class="sonata-ba-field col-sm-9 sonata-ba-field-standard-natural"
        >
            {# Render each groups role #}
            {% for label, choices in form.roles.vars.choices %}
                {# Render group role name #}
                <label>
                    <b>{{ label }}</b>
                </label>
                {# Render each roles of a group #}
                {% for key, choice in choices %}
                    {{ form_widget(form.roles.children[key]) }}
                    {{ form_label(form.roles.children[key]) }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% else %}
    {{ form_row(form[field_name])}}
{% endif %}
```

Then the roles form will shown like this

[image]